# How To Map Joypad Axis To Button?

Tags: root-access, buttons, game-controllers

How do I map a joypad (specifically the HAT switch/DPad) axis to a button with a key-layout file in `/system/usr/keylayout/`? I currently have this line in the appropriate file: `axis 0x10 split 0x7f BUTTON_L1 BUTTON_R1`.

I'll explain the line token by token. First token refers to the input type. `axis` means I'm binding an axis.

Second token is the axis ID. The axis I want to remap is `0x10`.

The [Android developer's wiki page](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files) concerning key-layout files mention you can split an input axis into two outputs with `split` so I'm using it. The split is at the value immediately following `split`, in this case `0x7f`.

Input values below the split threshold map as the 1st token after the split threshold token. Here it is `BUTTON_L1`.

Input values above the split threshold map as the 2nd token after the split threshold token. Here it is `BUTTON_R1`.

However, when I use the line metioned above the axis does not map to anything anymore. Are you able to map device axes to Android buttons in the first place? If so, what is the proper syntax for it?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Split axes](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files) documentation:

> A split axis maps a Linux axis code to two Android axis code names, such that values less than or greater than a threshold are split across two different axes when mapped. This mapping is useful when a single physical axis reported by the device encodes two different mutually exclusive logical axes.

In the example they split a combined gas/brake axis into separate `GAS` and `BRAKE` axes:

`axis 0x01 split 0x7f GAS BRAKE`

Axis index `0x01` is the Linux input event code [`ABS_X`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/136057256686de39cc3a07c2e39ef6bc43003ff6/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L816). We're taking the `ABS_X` axis with a logical range of `0x00` < x < `0xFF` and splitting it so that x >  `0x7F` is mapped to [`AXIS_GAS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#AXIS_GAS) and values below `0x7F` are mapped to [`AXIS_BRAKE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#AXIS_BRAKE).

In yours:

`axis 0x10 split 0x7f BUTTON_L1 BUTTON_R1`

Axis index `0x10` is special, it's the Linux input event code [`ABS_HAT0X`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/136057256686de39cc3a07c2e39ef6bc43003ff6/include/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h#L827) which is a synthetic axis generated by the Linux input subsystem to make it easier to deal with hat switch inputs. Internally, HID gamepads don't represent D-pads as buttons or as separate X and Y axes. They're usually represented as a single rotational "hat switch" axis. Linux converts the rotational value into `ABS_HAT0X` and `ABS_HAT0Y` axes normalized to -1 < x < 1. These are seen as axis `0x10` and axis `0x11` in the key layout mapping.

So, the first problem is your threshold is wrong. To split the `ABS_HAT0X` axis you should use a threshold of 0.

The second problem is you're trying to map the split axes to button events, which isn't supported. You can only split an axis into separate axes.

Comment: Is there a way to map specific directions on the hat switch to buttons, since I can't `split` an axis? Or am I completely out of luck?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with key layout files.